# Postgres Docker: "postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory"

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am having weird issues with official postgres docker image. Most of the time it works fine, if I shut down the container and launch it again, I sometimes get this error but it's not every time:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

I am launching postgres image using this command:

```
 export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs) && docker run --rm --name postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_DB \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD \
  -p $POSTGRES_PORT:$POSTGRES_PORT \
  -v $POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DATA:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres
```

I keep variables in `.env` file, they look like this:

```
POSTGRES_USER=custom-db
POSTGRES_DB=custom-db
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345678
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DATA=/tmp/custom-db-pgdata
```

When I try to `echo` variables the values are there so I don't think I'm passing null values to docker env variables.

The directory on my host machine looks something like this:

```
/tmp/custom-db-pgdata
├── base
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 13407
│   ├── 13408
│   └── 16384
├── global
├── pg_logical
├── pg_multixact
│   ├── members
│   └── offsets
├── pg_notify
├── pg_stat
├── pg_stat_tmp
├── pg_subtrans
├── pg_wal
│   └── archive_status
└── pg_xact
```

Comment: Does the container still start and work or it shuts down with error?

Comment: The container starts OK but sometimes throws the error at which point its unable to start.

Comment: What do you have in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` without mounting volume? It seems, that your mounted volume does not contain that conf file

Comment: I am not familiar with docker, there is such kind of things happening with "snap" and apparmor in ubuntu. Due to sandboxing, the application does not see the filesystem available the same way as you and for example what is seen as `/tmp` directory is a `/tmp/somekindofid/...`

Comment: On many Linux distributions the `/tmp` is not (guaranteed to be) persisted. It may be using `tmpfs` (in memory), you can see if it is by running `df`; or it may be cleaned by some run script.

Comment: @Niklas OK I launched the image without mounting the volume and then I opened bash session while it was running, this is what's in the directory:

```
base          pg_ident.conf  pg_serial     pg_tblspc    postgresql.auto.conf
global        pg_logical     pg_snapshots  pg_twophase  postgresql.conf
pg_commit_ts  pg_multixact   pg_stat       PG_VERSION   postmaster.opts
pg_dynshmem   pg_notify      pg_stat_tmp   pg_wal       postmaster.pid
pg_hba.conf   pg_replslot    pg_subtrans   pg_xact
```

Comment: @DarioSeidl I'm on macOS. Ok I will try different directory

Comment: Have you made sure to stop existing container before creating new one? Also, you are using `rm` switch on your `docker run`, I wonder how you have started old container again, since old one gets deleted. You should include that missing .conf file into that volume, since that is the reason. Sometimes it loads it from somewhere else, but I don't know why, so I'm afraid to answer

Answer (score 3):

If it's inconsistent in how it works between executions on the same machine and same session (aka without rebooting) then something isn't mapping your directories properly. Finding what it is that's breaking will be difficult, more so since you're on a Mac. Docker on a Mac you has the extra bonus of running through a VM, so docker is mapping your local drive/path through to the VM and then mapping that into the container image, so there are two different layers where things can go wrong.

Dario has the right idea in his clarifying comments, you shouldn't rely on `/tmp` since that *also* has Mac Magic to it. It's actually `/var/private/somegarbagestring` and is different every bootup. Try switching to a `/Users/$USER/dbpath` folder and move your data to that, so at least you're debugging with one less layer of magic between data and database.